# Para cada RecyclerView un Adapter?

Tags: android

Una pregunta,por ejemplo para crear un recyclerView tengo que crear su adapter y poner el diseño dentro, ahora bien si quiero otro diseño necesariamente tengo que crear otro adapter??  en si seria cada recyclerView tiene su propio adapter y si quisiera otro tengo que crear otro adapter, es así disculpen la pregunta pero tengo duda.
Gracias

Comment: ¿ te refieres a instancias de un adapter o clases de adapter ?

Comment: si es la misma información o bien puedes aprovechar su estructura, puedes usar siempre un adapter con diferentes recyclerviews

Comment: quedo resuelto esto? Como se poblaria el RecyclerView trabajando de esta manera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tienes que crear otro Adapter, simplemente tienes que implementar `getItemViewType()` para definir tus diferentes tipos de vistas:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   switch(position) {
       case 0:
           return TIPO_A;
       case 1:
           return TIPO_B;
       case 2:
           return TIPO_C;
       default:
           return TIPO_A;
   }
}
```

Crea tus ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolderA extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mContent;
    public GroupViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        ...
    }
}

public class ViewHolderB extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImage;
    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        ...
    }
}

public class ViewHolderC extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImage;
    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        ...
    }
}
```

En `onCreateViewHolder()` retornamos el tipo de `ViewHolder` (Contenedor):

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TIPO_A: return new ViewHolderA(...);
        case TIPO_B: return new ViewHolderB(...);
        case TIPO_C: return new ViewHolderC(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

En `bindViewHolder()` enlazamos el tipo de vista a reciclar:

```
@Override
public void bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TIPO_A:
            ViewHolderA viewHolderA = (ViewHolderFirst)holder;
            ...
            break;
        case TIPO_B:
            ViewHolderB viewHolderB = (ViewHolderSecond)holder;
            ...
            break;
        case TIPO_C:
            ViewHolderC viewHolderC = (ViewHolderSecond)holder;
            ...
            break;
        ...
    }
```

Así podrías tener diferente tipos de vistas con diferentes caracteristicas en un único `Adapter`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, pero en que parte tendria que establecer el xml del diseño por ejemplo este LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_album, null);

Comment: hola, si te refieres a los .xml de las vistas, en donde defines tus ViewHolder que corresponderían a vistas diferentes ( ViewHolderA,ViewHolderB y ViewHolderC ). Más tarde específico en la respuesta.

Comment: Esta bien @Elenasys