# usar varios recyclerview con el mismo adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview

estoy usando el mismo adapter para varios recyclerviews, la duda que tengo es que dos de ellos estan en paralelo en la pantalla por lo  que es la mitad del recycler original por consecuente me sale en estos dos recycler la informacion amontonada como sale en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es: se puede arreglar de alguna manera o es mejor crear otro adapter para estos dos recyclerviews?

Comment: allí lo que varía son las vistas (2 xml) por lo tanto ocupas un Adapter con 2 ViewType. Ejemplos:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21611/se-puede-poblar-un-recyclerview-con-dos-adapters-de-xml-con-diferente-estructur y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6606/para-cada-recyclerview-un-adapter?rq=1

Comment: podes usar el mismo recyclerview del mismo xml para otro adaptador